# Selenium Auto Lister FACEBOOK BOT Unable to find path where listing photos are stored

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pickle

im not a programmer by all means and its lovely to have something like stackoverflow to help. Im trying to run this python bot that will basically auto list on facebook marketplace. the bot runs but when it goes to list something it cant detect the path of my pictures. the path is defined in a txt called items. i have sent the github to the project below and my error. been banging my head over this for days changing paths and picture names. Can anyone help? Appreciate your time thank you!

error screenshot: https://prnt.sc/2fA-P4qMJuSO
github project:

Comment: GITHUB PROJECT: https://github.com/GeorgiKeranov/facebook-marketplace-bot

Comment: Here are some resources you might want to look at, to help you get better results from SO: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [mcve].